# Integrating Jenkins with BitBucket Server

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-server

I have an Bitbucket Server that is running currently quite well.
I also have an Bamboo Server which crashed on me today so badly that I would need to reinstall the complete bamboo stuff again. (Plugins, Server etc.)

This was not the first time. The Atlassian team couldn't even help me, so I moved to Jenkins instead.

Everything works so far.
I checked on several posts on the Internet but didn't find anything really useful or up2date on my question.

Here is what I am planing to do:

Build every Branch on creation

If Build Succeeds notify BitBucket Server that Build was successful

Update Jira and start Code Review (already in place)

I'm currently missing only step 1 and 2 as step 3 is quite easy to do with the according plugins.
But I need step 1 and 2 as well as an pull request should not be mergeable if the branch itself was not successfully built.

If anybody already solved this, notify me and I will look into it right away

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Looked into a lot more documentation.

Comment: Hooking Jenkins as deep into bitbucket as bamboo would do is not that easy possible because bamboo uses a lot or rest api which is barly documented or explained what bamboo does to get a pull request acceptable if the build is a success. Well need to switch back to bamboo server :-(